# Checking if value present in a nested Map using lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a nested map as `Map<String, Map<String, Boolean>>` and would like to find if the inner map has at least one value as TRUE. I was able to do it using a loop but trying to do it using lambda expression

Using for loop:

```
        Map<String, Map<String, Boolean>> maps = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Boolean> test = new HashMap<>();
        test.put("test1", Boolean.FALSE);
        test.put("test2", Boolean.TRUE);
        maps.put("hey", test);
        Map<String, Boolean> testtt = new HashMap<>();
        testtt.put("test3", Boolean.FALSE);
        testtt.put("test4", Boolean.TRUE);
        maps.put("lol", testtt);
        Boolean val = Boolean.FALSE;
        for(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Boolean>> m: maps.entrySet()){
            Map<String, Boolean> mm = m.getValue();
            for(Map.Entry<String, Boolean> mmm: mm.entrySet()){
                if(mmm.getValue()){
                    val = Boolean.TRUE;
                    break;

                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(val);
```

Comment: _but trying to do it using lambda expression_ Can you please share that attempt?

Comment: Even the loop solution can be much simpler: `boolean val = false; for(Map<String, Boolean> mm: maps.values()) { if(mm.containsValue(Boolean.TRUE)) { val = true; break; } }`

Answer (score 3):

> I was able to do it using a loop but trying to do it using lambda expression.

Here is one way.  Here the lambda will be based on a `Predicate`

- first you need to stream the outer maps values (which is another map) and then stream the values of those.
- Then it's a matter of using `anyMatch()` with an identity lambda to find the first true value.

```
Predicate<Map<String, Map<String, Boolean>>> hasTrue = m -> m.values()
        .stream().flatMap(map -> map.values().stream()).anyMatch(a->a);

System.out.println(hasTrue.test(maps));
```

Prints

```
true
```

And a better way as suggested by [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger)

```
maps.values().stream()
           .anyMatch(innerMap -> innerMap.containsValue(true))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try changing the loop on something like this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Boolean>> maps = new HashMap<>();
boolean hasValue = maps
.values()
.stream()
.flatMap(m -> m.values().stream())
.anyMatch(b -> b.getValue());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't compile.  The problem is here -> `anyMatch(b -> b.getValue()`;  Did you try to run it?

Comment: I couldn't run it. I just sent it over my phone and try to help ASAP, but appreciate your comment. I will try to run it

Comment: Since you are streaming over `values()`, `b` is already a `boolean`, hence you can’t call `getValue()` but there is no need to do. Just `anyMatch(b -> b)` would do. But it’s still unnecessarily complicated. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75178483/checking-if-value-present-in-a-nested-map-using-lambda-expression#comment132669119_75178769)

Comment: @Holger Thank you, you are right, my misspelling